# I want to disable Microsoft Office word temporary on my machine

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I have an application which uses Office Word on particular click. I need to see behavior when word is not installed on my machine. Can we replicate this by doing some settings as I do not want to uninstall word.

Answer (score 2):

Go to the control panel.  Navigate to add or remove programs.  Click on "Microsoft Office..." (version information will be in place of ellipsis).  Click "Change" then when the dialog box appears for the Change process click the "Add or Remove Features" then Next then disable Microsoft Word and continue through the process.  To re-enable go back through the process and  enable Microsoft Word.

I recently needed to do this to test a new process on machine with MS Word and without MS Word.  This way is much faster than installing or copying your test code to a different machine that does not have MS Word installed.